# What VBScript command should be used to tell it to do nothing?

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

What command should be used instead of `Do nothing` below so as to tell it to do nothing? If I just leave it empty, `WmiPrvSE.exe` will cause high CPU usage.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Do
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'wordpad.exe'")
If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
    `Do nothing`
Else
    Wscript.Echo "wordpad.exe is running."
End If
Loop
```

Comment: If I just leave it empty, `WmiPrvSE.exe` will cause high CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave the "if" blank - the script is using high CPU because its completing the "if" check and is then moving on really quickly over and over and over because its not ebing told to stop and your CPU is getting through the instructions as fast as possible.

I think that what you are looking for is the `sleep` command:

```
If colProcesses.Count = 0 The
    WScript.Sleep(10000)
Else
```

This number is Milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) and is how long the process will pause for.  In the example above, it pauses for 10 seconds.

[SS64 Reference for WScript Sleep](https://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html)

Answer (score 1):

The command you're after would be `DoEvents`, except this concept does not exist in VBScript, nor would it help in your case either.

The reason for your high CPU usage is because the loop keeps looping performing the task over and over again. So its querying if wordpad is running over and over again, and when it does, the loop doesn't end, so it continues to do so.

What you'll want to do is limit the script to do it with a wait in between.

So your `Do Nothing` would be something like this:

```
starttime = timer
do: loop until timer = starttime + 1
```

The `+ 1` can be replaced to any number and it will wait that much time. For example, if you want to only check every 10 seconds, change it to `+ 10`.